# Unable to install Heroku toolbelt in Ubuntu AWS instance

Tags: heroku

The following error is thrown while trying to install the Heroku toolbelt in the default Ubuntu AWS 12.04 AMI based instance

ubuntu@ip-11-121-123-115:~$ **wget -qO**- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | **sh**

This script requires superuser access to install software.
You will be prompted for your password by sudo.

```
 sh: 7: [[: not found
 sh: 29: [[: not found
 Installation complete
```

Comment: Hey, Rpj - I've given you the right answer, so please don't forget to award the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `sh` is not a symlink to `bash`. Try

```
wget ...blah... | /bin/bash
```

and see if that helps.

--EDIT--

Ha! Would you believe it! Not 5 minutes after answering, I had the same problem. Here's the fix:

1. Download the install.sh file
2. Modify the line that says `sudo sh` to say `sudo /bin/bash`
3. Run it with `/bin/bash install.sh`

The cause is that on some Ubuntu's, `/bin/sh` is actually a link to `/bin/dash` (not `bash`). And the install script uses some bash-isms without actually checking to see if you're using `bash` or not.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This answer should be posted on Heroku's website.

Comment: I'm very confused. I am not seeing where I can do any of the three steps, and some of them seem mutually exclusive. For instance, how many commands are we giving to the terminal? Could you be so kind as to explain in explicit "type  this" steps for the rest of us?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by doing the following:

```
$ wget https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh
$ sudo sh install.sh
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: the first line worked! the second line tells me to add a path, but doing so doesn't stop that from happening, and nothing else seems to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ sudo wget https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh
$ sudo sh install-ubuntu.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing - it installs the whole toolbelt, but the script the OP is running is just for installing the `heroku` client (without `git` and `foreman`).

Answer (score 0):

When not logged as root, AWS buggs for hostname matching, try

```
$ wget https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh --no-check-certificate
$ chmod +x install.sh` first) 
$ ./install.sh
```

The fist line gives you the **install.sh**